# How to search for an element inside another one with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am searching for elements that contains a certain string with `find_elements`, then for each of these elements, I need to ensure that each one contain a span with a certain text, is there a way that I can create a for loop and use the list of elements I got?

```
today = self.dataBrowser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//tr[child::td[child::div[child::strong[text()="{self.date}"]]]]')
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are currently using to find the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to search within each element of a loop, something like this:

```
today = self.dataBrowser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//tr[child::td[child::div[child::strong[text()="{self.date}"]]]]')

for element in today:
    span = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "span")

    if span.text == "The text you want to check":
        ...do something...
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can.
You can do something like the following:

```py
today = self.dataBrowser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//tr[child::td[child::div[child::strong[text()="{self.date}"]]]]')
for element in today:
    span = element.find_elements(By.XPATH,'.//span[contains(text(),"the_text_in_span")]')
    if !span:
        print("current element doesn't contain the desired span with text")
```

To make sure your code doesn't throw exception in case of no span with desired text found in some element you can use `find_elements` method. It returns a list of `WebElements`. In case of no match it will return just an empty list. An empty list is interpreted as a Boolean false in Python while non-empty list is interpreted as a Boolean true.